# CRM 4 WorkingWithDynamicsCrm4.Plugin how to debug?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I use CRM 4.0 and VS 2008. I installed the CRM SDK and WorkingWithCRM4.Plugin (http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/companion/9780735623781/). 
I managed to deploy I think the plugin's dll with the PluginRegistration.exe tool which I for from the SDK.

I try to make the sample code from the WorkingWithCRM4.Plugin to work. The problem is, nothing seems to happen. I try to debug the code, but it seems I can't attach to the right process (w3wp.exe) or the Execute event is not called. Does anybody has experience with: WorkingWithCRM4.Plugin and tell me how can make it work or debug?

Comment: Did you exactly follow the instructions mentioned in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps I do:

1. Sign a key.
2. Build.
3. Register the Plug-in.
4. Place the generated .pdb file into the bin folder of the CRM.
5. Debug the plug-in by attaching it to the w3wp.exe process.
6. Trigger your plugin by triggering the related *Message* on the related *Entity*.

Note: Sometimes you may have to to do an *iisreset* if there is something wrong.